# Querying LDAP server on UDP

Tags: debian, ldap

I am trying to query an LDAP server (Active directory) over ldaps. The problem is that the only ports i have available (389 and 636) are UDP ports. TCP is not allowed by the firewall rules (which i don't understand myself, so don't bother asking:) )

I am not having much luck however.
Running the command

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://cmpname.dk:636 -b "ou=CmpName,dc=cmpname,dc=dk" -D "cn=devldap,ou=Service,ou=Misc acconts,ou=CmpName,dc=cmpname,dc=dk" -w "password123" -v
```

Gives the message:

```
ldap_initialize( ldaps://cmpname.dk:636/??base )
```

after which it hangs for a while and then returns

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Can i assume that this is because ldapsearch only attempts to contact via tcp? Can i make ldapsearch contact the UDP port somehow?

Or is the error something else entirely?

Basically: Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD only supports LDAP over UDP in a very limited way. Not much more than being able to query authentication methods available.

> [LDAP Search Over UDP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc717362.aspx)
>
> Active Directory supports search over UDP only for searches against
>   [rootDSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#root_dse). It encodes the results of an LDAP search performed over UDP
>   in the same manner as it does a search performed over TCP;
>   specifically, as one or more SearchResultEntry messages followed by a
>   SearchResultDone message, as described in [RFC2251]. This means that
>   the search response is not encoded as described in [RFC1798]. Only
>   LDAP search and LDAP abandon operations are supported over UDP by
>   Active Directory.

-

> root DSE (rootDSE): A nameless entry containing the configuration
>   status of the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) server.
>   Typically, access to at least a portion of the root DSE is available
>   to unauthenticated clients, allowing them to determine the
>   authentication methods supported by the server.

Comment: Heh, that would explain it